# Updating js variables

Tags: javascript, html

I have dynamically updated list. Each list element has text input and delete button. I have 2 problems:

1. when I delete a list item, leninputs in cloneLi doesn't change
2. when I enter a text value in the first list item, it is copied also to the new one (i tried also elmtInput.reset(), but no change)

Do you have an idea what's wrong?

html code:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" id="item1" name="item1" value="">
            <div>
                <a class="btn" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<input type="submit" value="New item" class="btn" onclick="cloneLi()">
```

js:

```
function cloneLi() {
    leninputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
    if (leninputs < 5) {
        var ul = document.getElementById("sortable");
        var elmnt = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
        var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById("sortable").appendChild(cln);
        var elmtInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[leninputs];
        elmtInput.setAttribute("name", "item"+(leninputs+1).toString());
        elmtInput.setAttribute("id", "item"+(leninputs+1).toString());
        elmtInput.setAttribute("value", "");
    } else {
        alert('Max number of items reached!');
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not actually _deleting_ anything, you are just _hiding_ elements by setting `display:none`. The `li` element is still part of the DOM, so is the `input` inside it - so of course it also still gets selected by `getElementsByTagName("input")`.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the 1th problem `onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();"`. And what about the second one?

Comment: Try `elmtInput.value = ""`.

Comment: How simple :-) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the button input from gettting selected with the other input elements, so be more precise in your selecting, and that will make your condition to have only five inputs as max instead of four correct because you were counting one plus input, you need to delete the li element instead of just hiding it and that keeps its input element as it is, you need to change the value of each new input cloned to avoid cloning the value as well

```js
var listsContainer = document.querySelector("#sortable");
document.querySelector("#add_item").onclick = function() {
  var inputLen = document.querySelectorAll("#sortable input").length, newList;
  if(inputLen === 5) {
    return alert('Max number of items reached!');
  }
  newList = document.createElement("li");
  newList.innerHTML = `
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" id="item${++inputLen}" name="item${inputLen}" value="">
        <div>
            <a class="btn" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>`;
  listsContainer.appendChild(newList);
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
.row {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.row div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.row div i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.row input {
  width: 85%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}
#add_item {
  display: none;
}
label {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
  font: bold 24px monospace;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" id="item1" name="item1" value="">
            <div>
                <a class="btn" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
            <div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<label for="add_item"><input id="add_item" type="submit" class="btn">New item <i class='far fa-plus-square'></i></label>
```